# Woocommerce aJax apply coupon code in checkout page

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce

I am moving the WooCommerce Coupon input field bellow order total by editing the `review-order.php` Checkout Page using [**this method**](https://monalieblog.wordpress.com/2016/08/05/add-coupon-field-in-woocommerce-checkout/)

but the problem is applying coupon with ajax is not working.
SO my goal is to implement the ajax feature on apply coupon.

So what I am trying 
My PHP ajax action function

```
function implement_ajax_apply_coupon() {

    global $woocommerce;

    // Get the value of the coupon code
    //$code = $_REQUEST['coupon_code'];
    $code = filter_input( INPUT_POST, 'coupon_code', FILTER_DEFAULT );

    // Check coupon code to make sure is not empty
    if( empty( $code ) || !isset( $code ) ) {
        // Build our response
        $response = array(
            'result'    => 'error',
            'message'   => 'Code text field can not be empty.'
        );

        header( 'Content-Type: application/json' );
        echo json_encode( $response );

        // Always exit when doing ajax
        exit();
    }

    // Create an instance of WC_Coupon with our code
    $coupon = new WC_Coupon( $code );

    // Check coupon to make determine if its valid or not
    if( ! $coupon->id && ! isset( $coupon->id ) ) {
        // Build our response
        $response = array(
            'result'    => 'error',
            'message'   => 'Invalid code entered. Please try again.'
        );

        header( 'Content-Type: application/json' );
        echo json_encode( $response );

        // Always exit when doing ajax
        exit();

    } else {
          if ( ! empty( $code ) && ! WC()->cart->has_discount( $code ) ){
            WC()->cart->add_discount( $code ); // apply the coupon discount
            // Build our response
            $response = array(
                'result'    => 'success',
                'message'   => 'successfully added coupon code'
            );

            header( 'Content-Type: application/json' );
            echo json_encode( $response );

            // Always exit when doing ajax
            exit();
        }
    }
}

add_action('wp_ajax_ajaxapplucoupon', 'implement_ajax_apply_coupon');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_ajaxapplucoupon', 'implement_ajax_apply_coupon');
```

and My script is

```
( function($) {
    $( document ).ready( function() {
        $( '#apply_coupon').click( function( ev ) {
            // Prevent the form from submitting
            ev.preventDefault();

            // Get the coupon code
            var code = $( '#coupon_code').val();
            var button = $( this );
            data = {
                action: 'ajaxapplucoupon',
                coupon_code: code
            };


           button.html( 'wait.');
           // Send it over to WordPress.
            $.post( wc_checkout_params.ajax_url, data, function( returned_data ) {
                if( returned_data.result == 'error' ) {
                    $( 'p.result' ).html( returned_data.message );
                } else {
                    setTimeout(function(){
                    //reload with ajax
                        $(document.body).trigger('update_checkout');
                        button.html( 'Apply');
                    }, 2000);
                    console.log( returned_data+code );
                }
            })
        }); 
    });
})(jQuery);
```

My AJax Action function return nothing Please help.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I know i am late, we got why submit not working .

As you shared article link - if we fallow the same then coupon code not working because you are using checkout coupon form inside checkout form means form within form so first remove form tag form coupon html and use like this:

```
<tr class="coupon_checkout">

    <td colspan="2">
    
        <?php
        if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
        exit; // Exit if accessed directly
        }

        if ( ! wc_coupons_enabled() ) {
        return;
        }

        ?>
        <a href="#" class="showcoupon"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> REDEEM A PROMO CODE/GIFT VOUCHER</a>
        <div class="checkout_coupon" method="post" style="display:none">

            <p class="form-row form-row-first">
            <input type="text" name="coupon_code" class="input-text" placeholder="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Coupon code', 'woocommerce' ); ?>" id="checkout_coupon_code" value="" />
            </p>

            <p class="form-row form-row-last">
            <input id="checkout_apply_coupon" type="button" class="button" name="apply_coupon" value="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Apply Coupon', 'woocommerce' ); ?>" />
            </p>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Then add jquery either your custom.js file or directly on footer page like this:

```
<script>
jQuery(document).on('click','#checkout_apply_coupon', function() {
    // Get the coupon code
    var code = jQuery( '#checkout_coupon_code').val();
    var button = jQuery( this );
    alert(code);
    data = {
        action: 'ajaxapplucoupon',
        coupon_code: code
    };
    button.html( 'wait.');
    // Send it over to WordPress.
    jQuery.post( wc_checkout_params.ajax_url, data, function( returned_data ) {
        if( returned_data.result == 'error' ) {
            jQuery( 'p.result' ).html( returned_data.message );
        } else {
            setTimeout(function(){
            //reload with ajax
            jQuery(document.body).trigger('update_checkout');
                button.html( 'Apply');
            }, 2000);
            console.log( returned_data+code );
        }
    })
}); 
</script>
```

Its working in my checkout page:
https://www.loom.com/share/7dfc833895d248f191ba327cf5290403

Answer (score 0):

```
data = {
                action: 'ajaxapplucoupon',
                coupon_code: code
            };
```

Should be:

```
var data = {
                action: 'ajaxapplucoupon',
                coupon_code: code
            };
```